# Merge categories to 1 category if do not meet requirements - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

My dataset currently contain a column listing many competitors. I only want to retain 2 competitors (eg, ABC and KLM), and combine the rest into 1 category called Others.

For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"competitors": ["ABC", "DEF", "123", "456", "XYZ", "KLM"]})
```

desired output:

```
    competitors      new_competitors
0           ABC          ABC
1           DEF          others
2           123          others
3           456          others
4           XYZ          others
5           KLM          KLM
```

Thank you!

Comment: `np.where`, `pd.Series.where` with `pd.Series.isin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"competitors": ["ABC", "DEF", "123", "456", "XYZ", "KLM"]})

df['new_competitors'] = [x if x in ['ABC', 'KLM'] else 'others' for x in df['competitors']]
```

Comment: Thanks @MusHusKat for the tip, I actually was thinking of an if else statement for could not get it right! cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['new_competitors'] = df['competitors'].where(df['competitors'].isin(['ABC','KLM']), 'other')
```

Output:

```
  competitors new_competitors
0         ABC             ABC
1         DEF           other
2         123           other
3         456           other
4         XYZ           other
5         KLM             KLM
```